# Setting airplane_mode_on has moved from android.provider.Settings.System to android.provider.Settings.Global, returning read-only value

Tags: java, android, image, android-activity, airplane-mode

I am trying to load image in activity from another one  , When I click on the button to start activity it shows me black screen and never shows and give me this warning

```
 Setting airplane_mode_on has moved from android.provider.Settings.System to android.provider.Settings.Global, returning read-only value.
```

here is the activity .....

```
public class FinalActivity extends Activity  {

    private final static String TAG = "ICA";
    private ImageView imageViewThumbnail;
    protected Bitmap mFilterBitmap;
    private int[] mColors;
    private String filePath;
    private int chooserType;
    private boolean isActivityResultOver = false;
    private String originalFilePath;
    private String thumbnailFilePath;
    private String thumbnailSmallFilePath;
    Global mGlobal;
    ProgressDialog mDialog;
    ImageView saveIcon,  filterIcon;
    String[] frames = {
            "frame_1", "frame_2", "frame_3", "frame_4", "frame_5",
            "frame_6", "frame_7", "frame_8", "frame_9",
            "frame_10", "frame_11", "frame_12", "frame_13",
            "frame_14", "frame_15", "frame_16", "frame_17",
            "frame_18", "frame_19", "frame_20"};
    InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;
    AdRequest mAdRequest;
    ImageView mImageViewFrame;
    int pos;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.i(TAG, "Activity Created");
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_final);
        mGlobal = (Global) getApplicationContext();
        imageViewThumbnail = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.selectedimage);
        saveIcon = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageSave);
        filterIcon = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.editImage);
        mImageViewFrame = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.frameimage);
//        mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
//        mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.admob_intersitials));
//        mAdRequest= new AdRequest.Builder().build();
//        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(mAdRequest);
        imageViewThumbnail.setOnTouchListener(new MultiTouchListener());
        mDialog = Utils.SetProgressBar(mDialog, FinalActivity.this);
        mDialog.dismiss();

        loadImage(imageViewThumbnail, mGlobal.getPath());

        String result = getIntent().getStringExtra("resultpos");
        pos = Integer.parseInt(result);
        Log.w("Position===", "" + pos);
        String imagevalue = frames[pos];
        Log.w("imagename=====++++", "" + imagevalue);
        int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(imagevalue, "drawable", getPackageName());
        mImageViewFrame.setImageResource(resID);
        saveIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
//                if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
//                    mInterstitialAd.show();
//                }
                RelativeLayout view = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
                view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                view.buildDrawingCache();
                Bitmap bm = view.getDrawingCache();
                SaveImage(bm);
            }
        });
        filterIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                RelativeLayout view = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
                view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                view.buildDrawingCache();
                Bitmap bm = view.getDrawingCache();
                EditImage(bm);

            }
        });

    }

    private void SaveImage(Bitmap finalBitmap) {
        String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        File myDir = new File(root + "/HijabPhoto");
        myDir.mkdirs();
        Random generator = new Random();
        int n = 10000;
        n = generator.nextInt(n);
        String fname = "Image-" + n + ".jpg";
        File file = new File(myDir, fname);
        if (file.exists()) file.delete();
        try {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
            Toast.makeText(FinalActivity.this, "Image Saved Successfully.....", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.w("FILE PATH===", file.getPath().toString());
            String path = file.getPath().toString();
            addImageToGallery(path, FinalActivity.this);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
//            if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
//                mInterstitialAd.show();
//            }
            Intent sharin = new Intent(FinalActivity.this,ShareActivity.class);
            sharin.putExtra("path",fname);
            Log.w("file path",""+file.getPath().toString());
            startActivity(sharin);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    private void EditImage(Bitmap finalBitmap) {
        String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        File myDir = new File(root + "/HijabPhoto");
        myDir.mkdirs();
        Random generator = new Random();
        int n = 10000;
        n = generator.nextInt(n);
        String fname = "Image-" + n + ".jpg";
        File file = new File(myDir, fname);
        if (file.exists()) file.delete();
        try {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
            Log.w("FILE PATH===", file.getPath().toString());
            String path = file.getPath().toString();
            addImageToGallery(path, FinalActivity.this);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
//            if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
//                mInterstitialAd.show();
//            }
            Intent efficatIntent = new Intent(FinalActivity.this,EffictActivity.class);
            efficatIntent.putExtra("path",fname);
            Log.w("file path",""+file.getPath().toString());
            startActivity(efficatIntent);
            finish();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public static void addImageToGallery(final String filePath, final Context context) {

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN, System.currentTimeMillis());
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");
        values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, filePath);
        context.getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
    }

    private void loadImage(ImageView iv, final String path) {
        if(!isAirplaneModeOn(this.getApplicationContext())) {
            Picasso.with(FinalActivity.this)
                    .load(Uri.fromFile(new File(path)))
                    .fit()
                    .centerInside()
                    .into(iv, new Callback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess() {
                            Log.i(TAG, "Picasso Success Loading Thumbnail - " + path);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError() {
                            Log.i(TAG, "Picasso Error Loading Thumbnail Small - " + path);
                        }
                    });
        }
        else{
            //do something else?
        }

        File image = new File(path);
        BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image.getAbsolutePath(), bmOptions);
        engrave(bitmap);

//        bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap,parent.getWidth(),parent.getHeight(),true);
    }

    public void engrave(Bitmap mOriginalImageView) {

        final int width = mOriginalImageView.getWidth();
        final int height = mOriginalImageView.getHeight();
        Bitmap bitmap;
        //Convert bitmap to drawable
        Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), mOriginalImageView);
        mColors = AndroidUtils.drawableToIntArray(drawable);

        OilFilter filter = new OilFilter();
        filter.setLevels(1);
        filter.setRange(1);
        mColors = filter.filter(mColors, width, height);


        setModifyView(mColors, width, height);

    }

    protected void setModifyView(int[] colors, int width, int height) {
//        mImageView.setWillNotDraw(true);

        if (mFilterBitmap != null) {
            mFilterBitmap.recycle();
            mFilterBitmap = null;
        }

        mFilterBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(colors, 0, width, width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
//        mImageView.setImageBitmap(mFilterBitmap);
//        mImageView.setWillNotDraw(false);
//        mImageView.postInvalidate();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Saving Stuff");
        Log.i(TAG, "File Path: " + filePath);
        Log.i(TAG, "Chooser Type: " + chooserType);
        outState.putBoolean("activity_result_over", isActivityResultOver);
        outState.putInt("chooser_type", chooserType);
        outState.putString("media_path", filePath);
        outState.putString("orig", originalFilePath);
        outState.putString("thumb", thumbnailFilePath);
        outState.putString("thumbs", thumbnailSmallFilePath);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            if (savedInstanceState.containsKey("chooser_type")) {
                chooserType = savedInstanceState.getInt("chooser_type");
            }
            if (savedInstanceState.containsKey("media_path")) {
                filePath = savedInstanceState.getString("media_path");
            }
            if (savedInstanceState.containsKey("activity_result_over")) {
                isActivityResultOver = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("activity_result_over");
                originalFilePath = savedInstanceState.getString("orig");
                thumbnailFilePath = savedInstanceState.getString("thumb");
                thumbnailSmallFilePath = savedInstanceState.getString("thumbs");
            }
        }
        Log.i(TAG, "Restoring Stuff");
        Log.i(TAG, "File Path: " + filePath);
        Log.i(TAG, "Chooser Type: " + chooserType);
        Log.i(TAG, "Activity Result Over: " + isActivityResultOver);
        if (isActivityResultOver) {
            populateData();
        }
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }

    private void populateData() {
        Log.i(TAG, "Populating Data");
        loadImage(imageViewThumbnail, thumbnailFilePath);
//        loadImage(imageViewThumbSmall, thumbnailSmallFilePath);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.i(TAG, "Activity Destroyed");
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
    public static boolean isAirplaneModeOn(Context context) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
            return Settings.System.getInt(context.getContentResolver(),
                    Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, 0) != 0;
        } else {
            return Settings.Global.getInt(context.getContentResolver(),
                    Settings.Global.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, 0) != 0;
        }
    }
}
```

any help please

Comment: Were you able to fix this one?

Answer (score 4):

Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON was deprecated in API level 17.

You can see the reference [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.System.html#AIRPLANE_MODE_ON)

You have to replace Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON by AIRPLANE_MODE_ON on your isAirplaneModeOn method importing the one with Global in Settings [image: like below]

Comment: I found a similar issue on my device: "Setting auto_time_zone has moved from android.provider.Settings.Systemto android.provider.Settings.Global, returning read-only value."; process: com.andoid.phone; user: radio. But package "com.android.phone" is default app. Why is it going? Is the one solution - replace "com.android.phone"?